ffmpeg creating an MP3 from M3U playlist using crossfader doesnt work when M3U file contains greater than 11 Mp3's
I have created a PS script to make a single mixed MP3 output from my M3U files using ffmpeg and crossfader.
All works except when I have tried to create a single output of around 60 minutes or longer.  60 minutes is generally about 12 or 13 mp3 files from my library, if I have an M3U with 11 files in I get the expected output.mp3, when I have more files the ffmpeg command just stops.
this is an example of a ffmpeg command with 10 files created with PS
F:\Mindful\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation 101\Increase Brain Power.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\meditation6\Deep Contemplation Music 399.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation Music 2\174 Hz Eliminate Physical Energy Pain & Karma.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation 101\Sentimentality.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\meditation6\Zen Ambiance Music 122.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation 101\Glimmering Rainbow.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\meditation6\Natural White Noise 666.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation Music 1\Hearts of Freedom.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation7\Spirit Guide.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation7\Breath of Life.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation Music 2\963 Hz Cleanse Aura.mp3'  -vn -filter_complex "[0][1]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[01]; [01][2]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[02]; [02][3]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[03]; [03][4]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[04]; [04][5]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[05]; [05][6]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[06]; [06][7]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[07]; [07][8]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[08]; [08][9]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[09]; [09][10]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri" F:\Mindful\MediaIN\2_MP3FromM3U\Meditation\T60\Meditation_T60_20240803-163323.mp3

this is the output file size and duration as expected
-a----        03/08/2024     17:45       43368911 Meditation_T60_20240803-163323.mp3

this is the same M3U with 12 files
F:\Mindful\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation 101\Increase Brain Power.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\meditation6\Deep Contemplation Music 399.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation Music 2\174 Hz Eliminate Physical Energy Pain & Karma.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation 101\Sentimentality.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\meditation6\Zen Ambiance Music 122.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation 101\Glimmering Rainbow.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\meditation6\Natural White Noise 666.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation Music 1\Hearts of Freedom.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation7\Spirit Guide.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation7\Breath of Life.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation Music 2\963 Hz Cleanse Aura.mp3' -i 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\MP3\Meditation\Meditation Music 1\Gratitude.mp3'  -vn -filter_complex "[0][1]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[01]; [01][2]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[02]; [02][3]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[03]; [03][4]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[04]; [04][5]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[05]; [05][6]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[06]; [06][7]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[07]; [07][8]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[08]; [08][9]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[09]; [09][10]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[10]; [10][11]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri" F:\Mindful\MediaIN\2_MP3FromM3U\Meditation\T60\Meditation_T60_20240803-163323.mp3 

this is the output file much shorter missing a lot of the files
-a----        03/08/2024     17:53        7325903 Meditation_T60_20240803-163323.mp3

I am good with PS but new to ffmpeg, I have spent some time in looking over other peoples issues with creating mp3 from m3u but not found anything to help with my problem, any suggestions or pointers in the right direction very much appreciated as I am at a loss.
ffmpeg version
ffmpeg version 7.0.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint


 libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100

example of ffmpeg running then just stopping with no error faileing to run the full command
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #1:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #2:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #3:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #4:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #5:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #6:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #7:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #8:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #9:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #10:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  Stream #11:0 (mp3float) -> acrossfade
  acrossfade:default -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to 'F:\Mindful\MediaIN\2_MP3FromM3U\Meditation\T60\Meditation_T60_20240803-163323.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: iso6mp41
    TCON            : New Age
    TIT2            : Increase Brain Power
    TDRC            : 2017
    purl            : https://soundcloud.com/spamusicrelaxationmeditation/increase-brain-power
    comment         : https://soundcloud.com/spamusicrelaxationmeditation/increase-brain-power
    TPE1            : Spa Music Relaxation Meditation
    TSSE            : Lavf61.5.101
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavc61.11.100 libmp3lame
[out#0/mp3 @ 00000271ef5e3180] video:0KiB audio:7092KiB subtitle:0KiB other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: 0.008565%
size=    7093KiB time=00:07:33.84 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed= 117x

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     F:\Mindful\utils\taglib-sharp\src\TaglibSharp\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\TagLibSharp.dll


maybe, wrong pad naming → [10] [11], add some letter → [x10][11] or just replace all with [x][11]

thank you for a reply but when I add a letter to the padding it fails [mp3 @ 000001e5ac973280] Invalid stream specifier: x0.     Last message repeated 1 times [fc#0 @ 000001e5ac972740] Stream specifier 'x0' in filtergraph description [x0][1]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[x01]; [x01][2]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[x02]

I'm sorry, forgot about 1st input, it has normal order → [0][1]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[x]; [x][2]acrossfade=d=10:o=1:c1=tri:c2=tri[x];...

@БаярГончикжапов thank you adding a letter as you suggested has fixed the issue many thanks
